# RTKPLOT not showing google map

Tags: javascript, html

I am using RTKLIB feature RTKPLOT. Google map is not enabled in it because it requires API key. I inserted google map API key in given htm file but a blank screen is shown while showing coordinates. The header part of htm file is first like this

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"
type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
```

After that i replaced it for inserting API key as follows.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"
  ->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key={XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXX}&v=3&sensor=false"
```

tell me where I am wrong .
complete code is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RTKLIB_GM</title>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"
type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
var marks = [];
var markh = null;
var markz = 0;
var info = null;
var icon0="http://maps.google.co.jp/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png";
var icon1="http://maps.google.co.jp/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png";
function init() {
var opt = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
    zoom: 2, minZoom: 2,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),opt);
document.getElementById('state').value='1';
}
function SetView(lat,lon,zoom) {
if (map == null) return;
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon));
map.setZoom(zoom);
} 
function SetCent(lat,lon) {
if (map == null) return;
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon));
}

function SetZoom(zoom) {
if (map == null) return;
map.setZoom(zoom);
}
function ClearMark(lat,lon,title) {
for (var i in marks) {
    marks[i].setMap(null);
}
marks.length = 0;
markh = null;
}

function AddMark(lat,lon,title,msg) {
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
var opt = {map: map, position: pos, title: title, icon: icon1};
var mark = new google.maps.Marker(opt);
if (title == "SOL2") mark.setIcon(icon0);
google.maps.event.addListener(mark,'click',function(event) {
    if (info) {info.close();}
    info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: msg});
    info.open(mark.getMap(),mark);
});
marks.push(mark);
}

function PosMark(lat,lon,title) {
for (var i in marks) {
    if (marks[i].title==title) {
        marks[i].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon));
        break;
    }
}
}

function ShowMark(title) {
for (var i in marks) {
    if (marks[i].title==title) {
        marks[i].setVisible(true);
        break;
    }
}
}

function HideMark(title) {
for (var i in marks) {
    if (marks[i].title==title) {
        marks[i].setVisible(false);
        break;
    }
}
}

</script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;"; scroll="no"; onload="init()">
<div id="map" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"> </div>
<input id="state" type="hidden" value="0">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using htm or html? Can you post the entire source code?

Comment: sorry its html file. In this html file i have made changes

Comment: yes i can write entire code

Comment: code is too big to post here

Comment: Can you at least share the pertinent bits? Can you also edit the question to correctly reflect HTML use?

Comment: let me edit question and write entire code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Windows. You need to add a register key for the software to work.

Add the following entry of Windows registries by regedit (Registry Editor) to run the WebBrowser component on RTKPlot.exe as IE 11.

- Key: KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - SOFTWARE - Wow6432Node - Microsoft - Internet Explorer - MAIN - FeatureControl - FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
- Name: rtkplot.exe
- Type: REG_DWORD
- Data: 11000 (decimal)

http://www.rtklib.com/rtklib_support.htm - the same issue exists for NTRIP Browser (srctblbrows.exe)

This made it work on my machine, I had the same issue you had.

Comment: Great that the answer was accepted and could help you!